# Salesforce Apex Class and VisualForce

Tags: apex, visualforce, query

[image]I have created a class and page . And Take two custom fields in opportunity Object Rating__c and Category __c .I manually insert some products in Opplineitem and Set their rating and category .my question is that i want to sort the order category wise .By  Inserting some logic in my apex class for sorting please help

My apex class

```
public class OpportunityProduct {
    Public String opportunityId;
    Public Set<id> setId;
    public list<Product2> prdList{get;set;}

    public opportunityProduct(ApexPages.StandardController controller){

        opportunityId=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'); 
        system.debug('zzzzzzz-'+opportunityId);

        list<opportunity> oppList = new list<opportunity>();
        setId = new set<id>();

        oppList = [SELECT id ,(SELECT id,Product2Id FROM opportunitylineitems)
                   FROM opportunity 
                   WHERE id =:opportunityId];
        system.debug('zzzzz'+oppList);

        for(opportunity opp:oppList){
            if(opp.opportunitylineitems!=Null){
                for(opportunitylineitem oli: opp.opportunitylineitems){
                    if(oli.Product2Id!=null){
                        system.debug('==oli=>'+oli);
                    }
                    setId.add(oli.Product2Id);
                    System.debug('zzzzzzzzz'+setId);  
                }
            }
        }

        prdList = [SELECT Name,Category__c,Rating__c 
                   FROM Product2 
                   WHERE id IN: setId ORDER BY Category__c, Rating__c Asc];
        system.debug('zzzzzzzzz'+prdList);
    }
}
```

My Page

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardController="Opportunity" extensions="OpportunityProduct" >
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Product details">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!prdList}" var="pro">
                <apex:column value="{!pro.id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pro.name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pro.Rating__c}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!pro.Category__c}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want to display the data in four different tables if you have four categories.

For that you will have to create a map with `Category` as the `key` and `List<Product2>` as its `value`.

See below example:

**Controller Code:**

```
/******
****Declare this productCategoryMap at the top so that it is accessible in visualforce page    
*******/
Map<String, List<Product2>> productCategoryMap = new Map<String, List<Product2>>(); 

for (Product2 p : [SELECT Name,Category__c,Rating__c FROM Product2 WHERE id IN: setId ORDER BY Category__c, Rating__c Asc]) {
    if (!productCategoryMap.containsKey(p.Category__c)) {
        productCategoryMap.put(p.Category__c, new List<Product2>{p});
    }
    else {
        productCategoryMap.get(p.Category__c).add(p);
    }
}
```

**Visualforce code**

```
<apex:repeat value="{!productCategoryMap}" var="category">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="{!category}">
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="productCategoryMap[category]" var="product">
            <apex:column value="{!product.Name}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!product.Rating__c}"/>
            <apex:column value="{!product.Category__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:repeat>
```

Here for each category a list is created in `productCategoryMap`. So all unique categories will be populated as a key and the products related to that category are stored as value against each category.

In visualforce, we display the `key` of the map as `pageBlockSection` title and we get the list for that category using the category key.

Comment: Hello Hemant Can you Please tell me the flow of code

Comment: I didn't get u. Can you elaborate, what you are not able to understand? Didn't this work?

Comment: This Code work absolutely Fine thanks to you . Just Wanted to know how this code is working .I didn't get it .Please Explain

Comment: updated the answer with some more details

Answer (score 0):

In the SOQL query use `ORDER BY` properly. You can also define `ASC` or `DESC` for each field which you want to sort. Here is an example, the same principle applies to other queries.

```
SELECT Name,Category__c,Rating__c 
                   FROM Product2 
                   WHERE id IN: setId ORDER BY Category__c ASC, Rating__c Asc
```

Comment: I want A section Category wise in my Page

Comment: What you have tried so far and where you are stuck

Comment: Please see the vf page pic that i inserted . I just need to do 4 sections of Pageblocktable category wise .Thats it Thanks